# How to fill into the buffer with time and ID

Tags: c, arrays

This is a part of my program in which `buffUsed = 0` and `buffSize = 10` and the buffer is filled when it receives data and the first 8bytes are filled with time and CAN ID and the rest 8 bytes are filled with data of the CAN frame. Is there any simple way to fill the first 8 bytes of the buffer with time and ID

```
  buffer = (char *)malloc(buffSize*(16); 
  time_t t = time(NULL);
  struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);                                                                            
  long microTs; 

  long uSec()
  {
   struct timeval start;
   long mtime;
   gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
   mtime = start.tv_sec + start.tv_usec;
   return mtime;
  }

  if((buffer != NULL) && (buffUsed < buffSize))
            {              
                microTs = uSec();
                buffer[0+16*buffUsed] = tm->tm_mday;
                buffer[1+16*buffUsed] = tm->tm_mon +1;
                buffer[2+16*buffUsed] = (tm->tm_year)%100;
                buffer[3+16*buffUsed] = tm->tm_hour;
                buffer[4+16*buffUsed] = tm->tm_min;
                buffer[5+16*buffUsed] = tm->tm_sec;
                buffer[6+16*buffUsed] = microTs;
                buffer[7+16*buffUsed] = frameRd->can_id;

            }

            for(i=8;i<16;i++)
            {
              buffer[i+16*buffUsed] = frameRd->data[i-8];
            }             
           buffUsed++;
           }
```

Comment: This does not work?

Comment: What is `buffer` ?

Comment: This works fine, but  need more simplified way rather than filling each byte till first 8 bytes.

Comment: `buffer = (char *)malloc(buffSize*(16);`

Comment: There are only 256 microseconds?

Comment: regarding: `buffSize = 10`  Per the rest of your question this variable should be set to (at least) 16

Comment: regarding: `buffer = (char *)malloc(buffSize*(16);`  1) the returned type from any of the heap allocation functions ( `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` ) is `void*`, which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2)   Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Also, this seems to be allocating room for 16 instances of 'bufsize' and is using a 'magic' number `16`.  'magic' numbers make the code obscure.  Suggest using `#define` to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name

Comment: this kind of statement: `buffer[7+16*buffUsed]` will NOT properly calculate the offset into the buffer. Suggest: `buffer[7*16]`.   Similar considerations apply to the similar statements

Comment: regarding: `mtime = start.tv_sec + start.tv_usec;`  This statement will calculate garbage.  suggest: `mtime = (start.tv_sec*1000000) + start.tv_usec;` so the calculated value is in microseconds

Comment: the posted code is nesting a function inside another function.  A very poor practice (and currently, only `gcc` allows it)  Please post a [mcve] so we can help you with your code

Comment: the fields in the tm struct and not single byte fields.  Infact, they are each integers (typically 4 bytes each)

Answer (score 2):

suggest a struct like:

```
struct timeInUsec
{
    ...
};
struct MYDATA
{
    struct timeInUsec timeFields;
    char ID[8];
};
```

then direct/assign each of the field separately.

```
#define MAX_ENTRIES  10

buffer[ MAX_ENTRIES ][ sizeof struct MYDATA  ];
```

would be a one way to declare the buffer

However, the data being placed in the buffer are integers, so will need some manipulation to fit into single byte fields